# Greasemonkey setTimeout and setInterval not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, settimeout

I am using the following code, The only alert I get is the `alert(t)`. I have tried `unsafeWindow.setTimeout`, `window.setTimeout`, and other variations including setInterval - nothing is working.

```
$('#on').change(function () { t = setTimeout(function () { starttimer() },1000);timer_on = true;alert(t);  });
    function starttimer() { 
    alert('triggered');
        if (timer_on) {
            alert('timerstarted');
            t = setTimeout(function () { startimer() },1000);
            }
    }
```

Edit: No errors, either. The script continues to execute and `t` has a normal value, just the function never runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write code like that!  Learn to love [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

What version of FF and Greasemonkey are you using?  Some combos had problems with alerts inside timers and/or event listeners.

Anyway, `$('#time').val ()` is probably not present or not what you think it is.  Does `$('#time')` refer to an `<input>`?

Try this code:

```
// t and timer_on are global variables.

$('#on').change ( function () {
    var timeVal = $('#time').val ()  ||  1; //-- Account for empty and NaN
    timeVal     = parseInt (timeVal, 10) * 1000;

    alert ('Time val = ' + timeVal);
    t           = setTimeout (starttimer, timeVal);
    timer_on    = true;
    alert (t);
} );

function starttimer () {
    alert ('triggered');
    if (timer_on) {
        alert ('timerstarted');
        var timeVal = $('#time').val ()  ||  1; 
        timeVal     = parseInt (timeVal, 10) * 1000;

        alert ('Time val = ' + timeVal);
        t           = setTimeout (starttimer, timeVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: JSBeautifier - thanks for the link, I'll run my code through that before posting it next time ;). And thanks, this now triggers the timer, however I am not sure why - $('#time').val() DID exist, I even checked it did with adding a checkTimeout with two params and alerting both, and the timer still didn't run after that.

Comment: Defaulting to `1` and/or the `parseInt` could explain it.  Also jQuery `val()` may not work as you expect if the node is not an input.

Comment: Please be more specific than that, EG: link to the target page and the complete script.  Is there AJAX involved?

Comment: Actually all I had to do was restart firefox without editing the code and it worked again. Is it just me or is that weird? And no, no AJAX. - I would link you to the page but it requires login and you would have to jump through several hurdles to even get to the page that I'm working off.

Comment: The code works, but depending on what's going on with $('#time'), your script could have undesired behavior. Also, please report your versions.  And you may be due for a complete restart of Firefox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7573/discussion-between-brock-adams-and-consciousness)